# collection_check_boxes undefined method `id' for {:id=>1,...} in Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `simple_form` and `collection_check_boxes` in this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@geo_path_media_type) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :category %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :required_fields, [{ :id => 1, :name => 'chris'}, { :id => 2, :name => 'damn'}], :id, :name, checked: [{ :id => 1, :name => 'chris'}, { :id => 2, :name => 'damn'}].map(&:id) do |b| %>
      <span>
        <%= b.check_box %>
        <%= b.label %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get the error:

> `undefined method 'id' for {:id=>1, :name=>"chris"}:Hash`

Using a collection like `User.all` works fine, i.e.:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :required_fields, User.all, :id, :name, checked: User.all.map(&:id) do |b| %>
```

Why can't I use a hash here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hash requires you to access the `:id` key using `hash[:id]`. Rails generate getter methods for all columns in an ActiveRecord class as a default, meaning you can call, for example, `user.id`.

You can use an [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html) to achieve this:

```
x = OpenStruct.new(:id: 1, name: 'chris')
x.id #=> 1
```

In your case:

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :required_fields, [OpenStruct.new(:id: 1, name: 'chris'), OpenStruct.new(:id: 2, name: 'damn')], :id, :name #.....
```

Hope that helps - let me know if you've any questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using this syntax `User.all.map(&:id)` you do the same as `User.all.map { |u| u.id }` and it works because `id` is an attribute of User.

In a case of a ruby `Hash`, you need to map by key, you can't call any AR attribute:

```
[{ :id => 1, :name => 'chris'}, { :id => 2, :name => 'damn'}].map { |u| u[:id] }
```